# What happens when an aboleth enslaves another aboleth who's enslaved a werewolf?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, charmed

I was doing a monster battle with some of my friends and there were two aboleths, aboleth #1 and aboleth #2. Aboleth 1 had a werewolf under control using their enslave power, and then aboleth 2 took control of aboleth 1. Can aboleth 2 now control the werewolf under aboleth 1's control?

Comment: While my stock answer to this is "hilarity ensues" the nested effects are of interest in the odd case that there are two aboleth's in the room - a case of "this town isn't big enough for the both of us" if there ever was one.  Interesting question on multiple effects and their interactions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aboleth 2 can't directly control the werewolf.  But it can send commands to aboleth 1 saying "tell your werewolf to do X thing" and aboleth 1 will have to obey.

The DM might choose to introduce rules to model that it's clunky and awkward for aboleth 2 to pass commands through aboleth 1, or the DM might handwave it and say that it works fine.

If aboleth 2 doesn't know about the werewolf, there are various things it could do to find out.  It could say "tell me about everyone you're controlling" or it could say "tell me about anything you could do that might allow you to escape or avoid my control" or it could say "don't communicate or give commands to anyone unless I directly order you to".

Aboleths have an 18 INT, and they're probably pretty accustomed to mind-control stuff, so it's very possible the aboleth will think to say something like this.

If aboleth 2 forgets to check for an enslaved werewolf and also forgets to forbid giving orders to enslaved creatures, then aboleth 1 can freely give orders to the werewolf.  In this situation, aboleth 1 might issue an order like "attack me", because every time it takes damage it gets a new save against its own charm effect.

(Note that the werewolf might actually be unable to attack aboleth 1, because the "charmed" condition prevents that.  It's unclear how that part of the "charmed" condition interacts with the rule "the charmed target is under the aboleth's control".  If the aboleth finds it can't allow the werewolf to attack it, the aboleth will need to find some other constructive thing to have the werewolf do.)

Comment: what if aboleth 2 does not know about the werewolf under aboleth 1's control can aboleth 1 still give the werewolf commands without aboleth 2 knowing.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, sort of, in a roundabout way

Here's what Enslave says:

**Enslave:**

> The aboleth targets one creature it can see within 30 feet of it. The target must succeed on a DC 14 Wisdom saving throw or be magically charmed by the aboleth until the aboleth dies or until it is on a different plane of existence from the target. The charmed target is under the aboleth's control and can't take reactions, and the aboleth and the target can communicate telepathically with each other over any distance.

This is a tricky one, because Enslave gives control over the target, but it doesn't elaborate on how that control manifests. Do you control the target like a puppet on strings? Do you just give them orders that they are compelled to follow? We don't know, the ability doesn't say.

Regardless of how the control is manifested, Enslave doesn't grant you control over anything that the target also has enslaved, because it doesn't say that it does. But that doesn't mean we can't control our enslaved targets enslaved target, it just requires a more indirect method of control. We force our enslaved creature to force their enslaved creature to do what we want. In essence, we're playing a sort of telephone game.

Aboleth #2 uses its control over aboleth #1 to force aboleth #1 to use its control over the werewolf to force the werewolf to do a particular task that aboleth #2 wants done.

It's a little complicated, but odds are good that this will never come up in normal play, because PCs generally don't control aboleths, so the DM is already in control of all aboleths involved anyways (and probably the werewolf as well).

Comment: A DM is still likely to give the creatures under his control, including the aboleths and the werewolf, their own personal goals each. As such, the question of control does play a role in normal play.

Comment: @EgorHans: At least if your "normal play" includes "two aboleths and a werewolf swim up to the pool-side bar", but yeah I had the same objection: if one is enslaved, it probably isn't happy about it.  And there's extra information / control lag if commands have to get relayed through another Aboleth before the werewolf can get the message about something only Aboleth #2 sees.